# How to track next tag badges?

Tags: support, badges, badge-tracking

See the below image:

[image]

This is in the user's profile, in the "Activity" tab. The above part is in meta profile, and the below part is in the main site profile. In meta, there is the option to track the next tag badge, while in the main site there is not this option.

Is there a way to track the next tag badges in the main site? Or things are displayed like this because I have tag badges in the main site, and not in meta? This second option makes me think that the option to track the next tag badges in meta will disappear once I get one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ability to track tag badges is a new "privilege" bestowed upon Trusted Users (20K reputation here on math.SE).  See the following Meta.SE question:

- [Can't track Tag Badges without 20k rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254052/cant-track-tag-badges-without-20k-rep)

Essentially, once you have no more privileges to track, you can track tag badges in that now useless spot. (I imagine that something similar happens on meta: there are no meta-specific privileges to earn — beyond the ability to participate on meta, which is still a main-privilege — so they display tag-badge progress there.)

---

The "poor person's" method of tracking tag-badge progress is to go to the [tags tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=tags) in your user "activity" profile.

[image: non-CW tag answer information from profile page]

If you hover over the number to the left of the tag-name, a tooltip pops up telling you the number and cumulative score of all non-CW answers you have posted in that tag. (Additional information may also appear.) We then have to remember the criteria for tag-badges, as listed in the [Badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges) page from the Help Center:

> - **Bronze.** You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-CW answers to achieve this badge.
> - **Silver.** You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-CW answers to achieve this badge.
> - **Gold.** You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-CW answers to achieve this badge.

No fancy bars, but it does the trick.

<sub>(Boy am I tantalisingly close to that bronze [axiom-of-choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/axiom-of-choice) badge!)</sub>